# Exact sequence of left $R$-module

Tags: modules, exact-sequence

> Let $f : X \to Y$ and $g : Y \to Z$ be homomorphisms of left $R$-modules.
>   Show that there exists an exact sequence of left $R$-modules
>   $$
> 0 \rightarrow \operatorname{ker}(f) \rightarrow \operatorname{ker}(g f) \rightarrow \operatorname{ker}(g) \rightarrow \operatorname{coker}(f) \rightarrow \operatorname{coker}(g f) \rightarrow \operatorname{coker}(g) \rightarrow 0.
> $$

**My try**: I want to construct a commutative diagram of abelian groups with exact rows and then use Snake lemma. I tried the following diagram
$$
{\rm ker}(f)\stackrel{i}{\longrightarrow}X\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow}f(X)\stackrel{}{\longrightarrow}0
$$
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!f \downarrow\quad\ \ \ \ gf\downarrow\ \quad\quad g\downarrow
$$
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!0\longrightarrow 0\ \ \longrightarrow\ \ \ \  Z\stackrel{{\rm id}}{\longrightarrow}\ \ \ \ \ Z
$$

Is this diagram commutative? How to construct a correct diagram? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a diagram of the same shape as yours with $X, Y, \operatorname{Coker} f, 0$ in the top row and $0, Z, Z, 0$ in the bottom row with the obvious maps. Then apply the snake lemma.

Comment: Great! Many thanks!